# Why are iMessages appearing on my iPad but not coming through on my phone?

Tags: iphone, ipad, messages

I think I have everything set up correctly but randomly this week I have had a few messages appear on my iPad and they have never come through on my iPhone. So I didn't even knew I had a message until I looked at the iPad.

Also, I have noticed that not all my iMessages are showing on my iPad. Can anyone help? Does this has to do with my iCloud backup? I am not great with all of this!

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem.  Looking at Settings > Messages > Send & Receive on both iPad and iPhone, my telephone number was listed under 'You can be reached by iMessage at' on both and was greyed out on the iPhone, but ticked on the iPad.

The fix was to:

(a) tap the telephone number on the Settings page of the iPad (*Settings > Messages > Send & Receive > You can be reached by iMessage*).  This removed the tick beside the number, and

(b) on the iPhone, disabled and re-enabled iMessage (*Settings > Messages*), and then enabled the telephone number (*Settings > Messages > Send & Receive*, and tapped the telephone number on *You can be reached by iMessage at* settings page.

A notification was then shown on the iPad:

> Your Apple ID and phone number are now being used for iMessage on a
>   new iPhone.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend that you first turn iMessage off, then back on. Do this on both devices:

1. Messages > iMessage (Off)
2. Messages > iMessage (On)

Next, check the addresses and phone numbers that you have registered to receive iMessages:

- Messages > Send & Receive

Ensure that all the addresses registered on your iPad are registered on your phone, and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

1. Let's understand that the messages you see on your iPad are the once sent to your registered mailed ID and the once you see on your phone are sent to your registered phone number. Use following setting and you should see all your messages on your phone but all of them may not be visible on your iPad.
2. Looks like your iPad's iMessage is registered with your mail ID but your phone is not. So simply go to Settings > Messages > Send & Receive > "Add Another Email".